# Do browsers load images anyway if their URLs are "hidden" in <script>?

Tags: wordpress, browser

Please help me to understand the following.

I generate an JS object with some kind of data using PHP (WordPress), like:

```
$data = array(
 array(
  'title' => 'Title 1',
  'image'  => 'https://example.com/image1.jpg'
 ),
 array(
  'title' => 'Title 2',
  'image'  => 'https://example.com/image2.jpg'
 )
);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myVar = <?php echo wp_json_encode( $data ); ?>;
</script>
```

Then I render my section via JS using `myVar` object and pass all image URLs (which are not displaying initially) to a service worker for downloading them into the cache.

But in Chrome (Network tab) I see ALL images being downloaded while the page is loading.

Is that regular browser behaviour or did I miss something?
I don't need them to be downloaded in the beginning, but only via SW or when my script reacts on a user event and changes image `src` tag.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't reproduce it. The $data array you posted here is malformed, `'title =>` should be `'title' =>`

Comment: It's just as an example. Missing quote is a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Ok, I imagined that, anyways, could not repro... If you put exactly this code on a php page, does it happens? I tried with this and nothing shows up on network tab nor sources (test.php on root of site): https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/67d425bc8cbcada314f8db22dead6a30